# Is it reasonable or common to use multiple unique return values in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a function:

```
public static function loginUser($username, $password)
{
    ...

    //if no record was found where the username was matched
    //then we fail the login request
    if(!isset($record)) return Login::FAILURE_INCORRECT_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD;

    ...

    //create a new user token object
    $userToken = new UserToken();

    ...

    //give the token back to the caller
    return $userToken;
}
```

There are two distinct return values; one is an error code, and the other is an object. I normally contest this type of programming; typically I would encapsulate the result code and context into another safely typed class... I may yet do this, but I am curious to know if this is reasonable or common in PHP.

Here is how I handle the call:

```
public static function handleLoginRequest($request)
{
    $result = new LoginResult();

    $token = Login::loginUser($request->Username, $request->Password);

    if($token === Login::FAILURE_INCORRECT_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD) 
    {
        $result->FailureReason = $token;
        $result->Successful = False;
        return $result;
    }

    //give the token back in the result
    $result->UserToken = $token;

    $result->Successful = True;

    //return the result
    return $result;
}
```

I also wasn't sure if this was more appropriate for StackOverflow or Programmers...

Comment: It's quite okay, but in your case it would be more common to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function should return a LoginResult object as you've indicated in the second method. You shouldn't check for magic values, it should be along the lines of

### LoginResult

Boolean:isSuccessful

String:failureReason

UserToken:token

Answer (score 0):

I'd say be consistent: `return false` in case of failure and one type of data if everything went well (e.g. Array). For me it's quite important to keep consistency in the entire application. So, by default I expect whatever data type in case of success (usually mentioned in the inline annotation to what to expect) and `false` in case of failure.

P.S. It's somehow the same as using `getter` and `setter` methods. Of course you don't have to use it, but it will make your application more solid in the long run. It's just a good practice.